# Bootstrap multiselect ios

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a problem with the Bootstrap Multiselect option. I use this on a webapp where the user had to select in which categories a product should be saved. The categories have 3 levels. It works on a desktop (safari, IE, chrome) but it doesn't work on iOs.

I've included bootstrap.min.js and bootstrap-multiselect.js and this html

```
<select id="category" multiple="multiple" name="category[]" class="form-control form-categories">
    {section name=i loop=$categories}
        <option value="{$categories[i].id}" {if $set.category|strstr:"|`$categories[i].id`|"}  selected="selected"{/if}>
            {section name=j loop=$categories[i].level max=$categories[i].level}&nbsp;.......{/section}
            {$categories[i].name}
        </option>
    {/section}
</select>
```

Anyone can help me out how to get this fixed on ios? On google I found that somebody solved it with including the boostrap.js and not the bootstrap.min.js but that doesn't help here.

Comment: Can you please elaborate doesn't work on iOS .. Is the layout breaking ? or are the options appearing fine but you are not able to select ? or anything else ?

Comment: Oh sorry, forgot about the real thing that doesn't work :)
Well the options are display correct, but I can select any item or scroll through the list. And when I try to "click" on an item, the dropdown just closes again.

Comment: you mean `can't` select any item ... right

Comment: Can you check this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v00qbqhf/). I have added some dummy options and this seems to be working fine on my iPad safari.

Comment: Yes I meant "can't" select of course! :)

Comment: Well the fiddle doesn't use the same multiselecter that I'm using. In my case it's a dropdown and you can use checkboxes to activate multiple choises.
https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect